# DotNetOpenAuth "This site failed verification."

Tags: c#, openid, dotnetopenauth

I have implemented an OpenID IdP and an RP.  They seem to be working-- the RP is contacting the IdP and is redirecting to the IdP for authentication.  The only problem is when I am on the authenticate/authorize page it says "This site failed verification."  I dug around in the code a little and saw a few things that it was doing.  I have a hunch that it has something to do with the Yadis document not being found.  My site's realm shoots off a 302 Found status code, so I thought this might be the problem and set it up to have an "Accept" request header which can be fed the Yadis document type ("application/xrds+xml").  Then instead of issuing the 302 Found redirect, it returns the document.

I also tried placing the X-XRDS-Location header... no go.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a nice rework, but once I fixed the 302 Found to a 200 OK response, I was golden.

http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/06/why-yahoo-says-your-openid-site.html